# How do I wget a page from archive.org without the directory?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a webpage from archive.org (ie http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110410223952id_/http://www.goldalert.com/gold-price-hovers-at-1460-as-ecb-hikes-rates-2/ ) with wget. I want to download it in /00001/index.html. How would I go about doing this?

I tried `wget -p -k http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110410223952id_/http://www.goldalert.com/gold-price-hovers-at-1460-as-ecb-hikes-rates-2/ -O 00001/index.html` but that didn't work. I than `cd` into the directory and removed the 00001 from the O flag. It didn't work either. I than just removed the -O flag. It worked but I get the whole archive.org directory (ie wayback.archive.org *new directory* web *new diretory* etc...) and the filename's not changed :(

What do I do?

Sorry for the obviously noob question.

Answer (score -1):

`wget http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110410223952id_/http://www.goldalert.com/gold-price-hovers-at-1460-as-ecb-hikes-rates-2/ -O 00001/index.html`

Solve my own question. So simple.